# How to simplify the Sentence "Failure is not Opposite of Success Failure is Part of it"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I am trying to simplify the sentence

> Failure is not opposite of success  failure is part of it.

Simplified sentence is :

> Failure is not opposite of success part of it.

Comment: Why do you want to simplify it?

Comment: The original sentence needs punctuation in order to make sense.

Comment: Could you update it as Answer Mr.Kate Bunting

Comment: Failure is a part of success, not its opposite.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple options that end in prepositions, which might get frowns but work for headings and natural English:
Failure is not the opposite of success, rather it is a part of it.
Failure is not the opposite of success, but part of it.

Non-preposition endings:
Failure is not the opposite of success, but rather its critical component.

Comment: Those sentences end in **pronouns**. No one objects to that.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is missing punctuation.  It contains two clauses, which should be separated with a semi-colon.  (A period would also be correct, but a semi-colon is more appropriate here, since the two clauses make up one idea.)

> Failure is not opposite of success; failure is part of it.

I would also suggest two other small changes:

The first clause has a small grammatical error, which you can fix by adding "the" in front of "opposite".

In the second clause, replace "it" by "success". Using a pronoun here is grammatically correct, but repeating the noun will make the sentence more effective.

> Failure is not the opposite of success; failure is part of success.

Comment: Nice answer. I have upvoted it. I might suggest two edits. Adding "the" before "opposite" corrects an error in grammar.  Replacing "it" by "success" is a recommendation, a good one in my opinion, about style. I would distinguish between the two.

Comment: Thank you.  I had pondered whether to list the changes separately;  I've gone back and done that.

Comment: You're welcome. Edit is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply say,  "failure is a part of success". In North American culture we often say, "fail forward". This means failing is part of the learning process and is a good thing. Make mistakes with the intention of learning from them  and don't repeat what does not work.